# TypeError: "state" is read-only

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm trying to render data from my axios request but I'm getting the error: TypeError: "state" is read-only. I'm trying to figure out how to just display the data from the get request on the phone screen. I've never done this before, but a lot of the articles I saw had people using the method below.

```
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState();

  state = {
    items: [],
  };

  const url = "";

  const getAPOD = () => {
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then(function (response) {
        // handle success
        let title = response.data.title;
        console.log(response.data);
        setState({
          items: title,
        });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{items.title}</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: remove  this => state = {
    items: [],
  };

Comment: I get the error ```ReferenceError: items is not defined```

Comment: I have added an answer step by steps and comment so you know how a functional component works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to set the state like below

```
 const [state, setState] = useState({items:[]});
```

You can assign the state directly like you have done.

Better change the code like below.

```
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    items: {title:""},
  });
  
  useEffect(getAPOD,[]);

  const url = "";

  const getAPOD = () => {
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then(function (response) {
        // handle success
        let title = response.data.title;
        console.log(response.data);
        setState({
          items: title,
        });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{state.items.title}</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: I get the error ```ReferenceError: items is not defined```

Comment: You will have to access state.items instead of accessing items directly in return

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Should I declare any other information that I get from my API in the state?

Comment: Its upto you, if you set the values are default you can show it till the data is loaded, and also you can return null if the state.items.title is empty

Comment: It seems to be coming back undefined hmm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224994/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-jonah-g).